# How to save brand_id Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

trucks table have `brand_id`. When I create a truck I want to save the `brand_id`.

Truck one to one Brand.

Migration Brands

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migration Trucks

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('trucks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('brand_id');
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->string('owner_full_name');
        $table->integer('number_of_owners')->nullable();
        $table->text('comment')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Model Brand

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function truck()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }
}
```

Model Truck

```
class Truck extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'trucks';

    protected $fillable = [
        'brand_id',
        'year',
        'owner_full_name',
        'owner_numbers',
        'comment'
    ];

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Truck Form (I am using https://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/) Form Builder

```
class TruckForm extends Form
{
    public function buildForm()
    {
        $this
            ->add('brand_id', Field::SELECT, [
                'empty_value' => 'Select Brand',
                'choices' => Brand::pluck('name')->all()
            ])
            ->add('year', Field::NUMBER, [
                'rules' => ['required', 'gt:1900', 'lte:' . Carbon::now()->year]
            ])
            ->add('owner_full_name', Field::TEXT, [
                'rules' => ['required', new MinWordsRule(2)]
            ])
            ->add('number_of_owners', Field::NUMBER, ['rules' => 'nullable'])
            ->add('comment', Field::TEXTAREA, ['rules' => 'nullable'])
            ->add('Save or Create', Field::BUTTON_SUBMIT, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success']
            ]);
    }
}
```

My need when create truck `brand_id` save being his brand

Truck Controller

```
public function create(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
{
    $brandForm = $formBuilder->create(TruckForm::class, [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'url' => route('trucks.store')
    ]);

    return view('landing.trucks.create', compact('brandForm'));
}

public function store(FormBuilder $formBuilder, Request $request)
{
    $brandForm = $formBuilder->create(TruckForm::class);
    $brandForm->redirectIfNotValid();

    $object = new Truck();
    $object->fill($request->all());
    $object->save();
    $object->brand()->save($request->input('brand_id'));

    return redirect()->route('trucks.index');
}
```

Comment: in Brand Model you have to add return $this->hasMany(Truck::class);
And in Truck model:  return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
And you have to use One to Many relations...

Comment: one Truck have 1 brand

Comment: Your relationship methods are switched around, since Truck has the `brand_id` it should have the belongsTo and Brand should have the hasOne, please read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) carefully. Additionally you can remove `$object->brand()->save($request->input('brand_id'));` since you are already saving the `brand_id` in `$object->fill($request->all());`

Comment: for Example TRUCKS ID = 1,BRAND_iD = 1, YEAR = 2000, OWNER_fULL_NAME, COMMENT.

Comment: I did as you said. But in my trucks in the database brand_id is not stored the numbers that should be. For example, I chose a Mercedes from him id 20 and I have saved 1.

Comment: Make sure that the correct brand id is provided in `$request->all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to validate your user inputs even if they came from an HTML `select` tag

```
//...
'brand_id' => 'required|exists:brands,id' // make sure your brand_id is a valid ID
//...
```

Then

Keep your controller simple

```
public function store(FormBuilder $formBuilder, Request $request)
{
    $brandForm = $formBuilder->create(TruckForm::class);
    $brandForm->redirectIfNotValid();

    $object = new Truck();
    // this line will map the brand_id attr to $obj->brand_id and link the 2 models to each others ...
    $object->fill($request->all());
    $object->save();

    return redirect()->route('trucks.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are switched around, as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), since the Truck has the `brand_id` it should have the `belongsTo` and Brand should have the `hasOne`, like this:

Brand model:

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function truck()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Truck::class);
    }
}
```

Truck model:

```
class Truck extends Model
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

And as you can see [here](https://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/overview/validation.html), you can simplify your store method to something like this:

```
public function store(FormBuilder $formBuilder, Request $request)
{
    $form = $formBuilder->create(TruckForm::class);

    $form->redirectIfNotValid();

    Truck::create($form->getFieldValues());

    return redirect()->route('trucks.index');
}
```

Or using the `FormBuilderTrait`:

```
use Kris\LaravelFormBuilder\FormBuilderTrait;
use App\Forms\TruckForm;

class TruckController extends Controller
{
    use FormBuilderTrait;

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->form(TruckForm::class);

        $form->redirectIfNotValid();

        Truck::create($form->getFieldValues());

        return redirect()->route('trucks.index');
    }
}
```